# I want to only accept the A to Z in my textfield . And do not accept the numbers in swift 5

Tags: swift, textfield

i created a username textfield and  i want my textfield do not accept the numbers in swift 5

i tried this bud didnt work

```
func OnlyCharacter(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
 let allowedcharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
 let characterset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
 return allowedcharacters.isSuperset(of: characterset)

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change only `CharacterSet.decimalDigits` to `NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()`

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.rangeOfCharacter(from: .letters) != nil {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool { 
    let non_digits = NSCharacterSet.letters.inverted
    let range = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: non_digits)
    if range != nil { // found an invalid
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Please do not answer with code only, add some context as to how this answer solves the question. This is not only helpful for the OP but for future readers of this question and answers

Answer (score 0):

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
      let characterSet = CharacterSet.letters //accept letters only here
      if string.rangeOfCharacter(from:characterSet.inverted) != nil {
      return false
    }
    return true
 }
```

Comment: Please do not answer with code only, add some context as to how this answer solves the question. This is not only helpful for the OP but for future readers of this question and answers